# sshpass no longer works?

Tags: ssh, sshpass

I'm trying to use sshpass to login automatically, however, it seems to have problem with `/dev/tty`

```
echo password | ./sshpass ssh root@xxxx
...
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
...
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password).
```

Any ideas? I can login directly without sshpass, so it's a tty problem.

Comment: I thought it's `sshpass -p password | ssh root@127.0.0.1`

Comment: @MichaelD. no, it should be `./sshpass -p password ssh root@xxxx`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sshpass` is used different way:

```
./sshpass -p password ssh root@xxxx
```

as explained in the manual page synopsis:

```
sshpass [-ffilename|-dnum|-ppassword|-e] [options] command arguments
```